# Какую js-библиотеку для работы с canvas выбрать?

Tags: canvas, javascript

Какую js-библиотеку для работы с canvas выбрать?

Я собираюсь использовать canvas для отрисовки математических издержек: графиков, графов, множеств и т.д. Способен отрисовать это все на canvas из коробки, но если вдруг существует какая-то супер-мего удобная библиотека, я бы хотел о ней знать.

Всем заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне для отрисовки графиков отлично подошла [библиотека Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/)

Comment: Примером своих работа не поделитесь?

Comment: разве штатных недостаточно? http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/